# Menu which summons other scripts

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, menu

I'm trying to make a script which is a main menu where every option summons another script. How should I do it?

I got in mind a case option for the menu, but I don't even know how to do a summon to another script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "¡Bienvenido -----!"
sleep 1
echo "¿A que departamento perteneces?"
echo "1.Sistemas"
echo "2.Correctivo"
echo "3.Producto"
echo "4.Empresa"
echo "5.Cliente"

read depart
    case "$depart" in
        1)
            echo "Seleccionaste sistemas"
            ;;

        2)
            echo "Seleccionaste correctivo"
            ;;
        3)
            echo "Seleccionaste producto"
            ;;       
        4) 
            echo "Seleccionaste empresa"
            ;;
        5)
            echo "Seleccionaste cliente"
            ;;        
    esac
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We're here to help you but we're not here to write the complete code for you. Please show us your efforts by providing your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Maybe use the keywords **shell script menu** with your favorite search engine and read the results...

Comment: Just call the other script. For example, `1)
            echo "Seleccionaste sistemas" ; script1
            ;;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

ENTRY1="Sistemas"
ENTRY2="Correctivo"
ENTRY3="Producto"
ENTRY4="Empresa"
ENTRY5="Cliente"
ENTRY6="Final"

Menu=("$ENTRY1" "$ENTRY2" "$ENTRY3" "$ENTRY4" "$ENTRY5" "$ENTRY6")

select your_change in "${Menu[@]}"; do
    case "$your_change" in
       $ENTRY1) echo "$ENTRY1" 
                # /path/to/your/script.sh
                ;;
       $ENTRY2) echo "$ENTRY2" ;;
       $ENTRY3) echo "$ENTRY3" ;;
       $ENTRY4) echo "$ENTRY4" ;;
       $ENTRY5) echo "$ENTRY5" ;;
       $ENTRY6) exit
    esac
done
```

Comment: It deppends... ` # /path/to/your/script.sh` does this summon another function?

Comment: Yes it is an example how to call another script or program. You can also code the commands directly at this position.

Comment: If the answer is helping you to find the solution, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and mark with a green hook, thx.